# Form Wont move down using Css

Tags: css, django

I have tried implementing some CSS to move my form up or down the page and I still cant get it to move and I don't seem to know why and I've tried using padding and margins and I still cant seem to get it to work and the css does appear on the page but nothing on it will move and they all just stay attached to the nav bar at the top of the screen. Attached is the html for the page and the CSS.

Css

```
.main2{
  top:40px;
  margin-left:70px;
  width: 90%;
  height:75%;
  background-color: #36454F;
  position:fixed;
  padding-top: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;




    }




.contact-form {
  float:right;
  background-color:white;
  margin-right:10px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top:28px;




   }
```

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 {% extends 'parasites_app/base.html' %}
 {% load static %}









 {% block content_block %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Contact.css' %}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"/>
<div class="main" >

<div class="main2">
    <form id="user_form" class="contact-form" method="POST" action='/Contact/' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="contact-container">

            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                {% csrf_token %}



                    Email<input type="text" name="Email" value="" size="30" />
                    <br />
                    Question<input type="text" name="Quesstion" value="" size="50" />
                    <br />
                    <!-- Submit button-->
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Send Request</button>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </form>



</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: get rid of the .main2 padding-top: 100%  ?

Answer (score 0):

Set your contact-form to be position:absolute.
Then you can put it wherever you want within the fixed container using top/right/bottom/left.